# nodejs serving static files (path issue) (unable to go down dir "/../")

Tags: node.js, express, path

**Short overview of the problem**

I am in the `routes.js` file, how do I serve all the files in the `css` folder as static files?

[path structure (someone edit this and make the img visible without use of link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3psih.png)

---

**Some failed attempts**

`path.join(__dirname, '\\css')` -> outputs -> `\\app\\routes\\css`

`path.join(__dirname, '..\\css')` -> outputs -> `\\app\\routes\\css`

`path.join(__dirname, '..', 'css')` -> outputs -> `\\app\\routes\\css`

---

The desired path is: `\\app\\routes\\..\\css`

But for some reason the "/../" is ignored. *See comments in `routes.js`*

---

**routes.js**

```
var express = require("express");

var path = require('path');


var appRouter = function (app) {

  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '\\css')));
   // RESULTS IN INVALID PATH: '\\app\\routes\\css'

   // (there is no css folder inside the routes folder) 

  app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.redirect('/home');
      });
};

module.exports = appRouter;
```

**server.js**

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var routes = require("./routes/routes.js");
var app = express();

const server_port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

routes(app);

var server = app.listen(server_port);
```

**Index.html**

```
        // I have linked to the static css file
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
```

---

**Additional info**

`app.use(express.static('app'));` works, however it serves all the files in the entire app folder, which is not desirable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

`path.join(__dirname, '/../css')`

(You need to add a `/` before directory name)

Comment: You solved it, just have to delete the "css/" part from the href in the `index.html` and everything works as intended.